# split string in tsql from column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a `column` in my table  with text (string) like **19.5** or **7.14** but as well with just **19** or **11**.

I want to split the **text** in **2 columns** 1 with all the text before the "." and 1 with all the text after the "." .

For the entries **without** a **.** in the string, the table must have **00** in the second column. Also all data after the **.** has to be 2 chars long(padded with 0).

e.g. **19.5** must give `column1: 19 column2: 50` ; **11** must give **column1: 11 column2: 00**
Can anybody help me with the correct tsql-code?

Answer (score 4):

Please try:

```
select 
    YourCol, 
    SUBSTRING(YourCol, 0, CHARINDEX('.', YourCol+'.')) Col1, 
    LEFT(SUBSTRING(YourCol, CHARINDEX('.', YourCol+'.')+1, 2)+'00', 2) Col2 
from YourTable
```

or

```
select
    YourCol,
    CAST(YourCol AS INT) Col1,
    RIGHT(PARSENAME(YourCol,1), 2) Col2
from
(
    select 
        CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2), YourCol) YourCol
    from YourTable
)x
```

Sample:

```
declare @tbl as table(txt nvarchar(10))
insert into @tbl values ('19.5'), ('11'), ('7.14')

select 
    txt, 
    SUBSTRING(txt, 0, CHARINDEX('.', txt+'.')) Col1, 
    LEFT(SUBSTRING(txt, CHARINDEX('.', txt+'.')+1, 2)+'00', 2) Col2 
from @tbl
```

or

```
select
    txt,
    CAST(txt AS INT) Col1,
    RIGHT(PARSENAME(txt,1), 2) Col2
from
(
    select 
        CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2), txt) txt
    from @tbl
)x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(cast(number as float) as int) column1,
right(cast(number as numeric(9,2)), 2) column2
from
(VALUES ('19.5'),('7.14'),('19'),('11') ) t(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Declare @InputList VARCHAR(8000), @Delimiter VARCHAR(8000);
Declare @1stvalue nvarchar(20), @2ndValue Int;

Set @InputList = '19.5';
Set @Delimiter = '.';

set @1stvalue = (select RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@InputList,1,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@InputList,0)-1))));

set @2ndValue = (Select RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@InputList,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@InputList,0)+LEN(@Delimiter),LEN(@InputList)))) )
set @2ndValue = (select case when @2ndValue < 10 then convert (varchar(10) ,convert (varchar(10),@2ndValue) + '0') else convert (varchar(10), @2ndValue) end);

SELECT @1stvalue AS Column1, @2ndValue AS Column2;
```

You can use this as function..